# Group categorical variables in glmnet

Tags: categorical-data, glmnet

Consider the following fit:

`fit3a=glmnet(x,g4,family="multinomial",type.multinomial="grouped")`

How do I indicate which columns in `x` are categorical/multinomial? Is there an option to specify the index of the grouped variables?

The documentation describes the option `type.multinomial` as follows:

> If "grouped" then a grouped lasso penalty is used on the multinomial
>   coefﬁcients for a variable. This ensures they are all in our out
>   together. The default is "ungrouped".

Answer (score 14):

The first two arguments that `glmnet()` is expecting are a matrix of the predictors (`x`, in your case) and a vector of the response (`g4`, in your case). For the `x` matrix, it is expecting that you have already dummied out any categorical variables. In other words, `glmnet()` does not actually know if any of your predictors are categorical, because they have already been dummied out.

If your data is in a data frame, a good way to construct the `x` matrix is using the `model.matrix()` function. It accepts formula language, will automatically exclude the response variable, and will create dummy variables for any predictors defined as factors.

The `family="multinomial"` and `type.multinomial="grouped"` options refer to the response variable having more than 2 possible outcomes. You can pass in the response variable (`g4`) as a factor.

The package authors provide a nice [vignette](http://www.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html) explaining the usage of `glmnet()`, though it unfortunately does not give an example using `model.matrix()` to prepare the `x` matrix.

Comment: A bit late to the party, but just to note that another nice introduction to glmnet, along with an example using model.matrix, is given in An Introduction to Statistical Learning. http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20First%20Printing.pdf

Answer (score 11):

As justmarkham points out, you can construct the design matrix `x` using `model.matrix`.  Note that you'll want to exclude the intercept, since glmnet includes one by default.  You may also want to change the default contrast function, which by default leaves out one level of the each factor (treatment coding).  But because of the lasso penalty, this is no longer necessary for identifiability, and in fact makes interpretation of the selected variables more complicated.  To do this, set

```
contr.Dummy <- function(contrasts, ...){
   conT <- contr.treatment(contrasts=FALSE, ...)
   conT
}
options(contrasts=c(ordered='contr.Dummy', unordered='contr.Dummy'))
```

Now, whatever levels of a factor are selected, you can think of it as suggesting that these specific levels matter, versus all the omitted levels.  In machine learning, I have seen this coding referred to as one-hot encoding.

Assuming that `g4` has `K` levels, the `type.multinomial="grouped"` option specifies that the features of `x` will all enter the model simultaneously for each of the `K` linear predictors, as opposed to having the linear predictor for each class (in general) having its own features.  `glmnet` does not (currently?) support grouped-type penalties of predictors (the `x` matrix).  The package `grplasso` does, but is written in pure R, so is slower than `glmnet`, but you could give that a try.

Comment: Could you perhaps explain this a little bit differently? Or (more to the point) perhaps you could provide insight to my related question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238623/using-deviation-coding-effect-coding-of-factors-in-glmnet-lasso-in-r

Comment: Hi @AndrewM, `model.matrix` doesn't exclude any level from the first categorical variable when we omit the intercept. Should the design matrix be an input in `glmnet` regardless? and how do we interpret the unomitted level of the first categorical variable in lasso regression?